# Enterprise apps for WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How are people handling the distribution for Enterprise apps on WP7?
I have an app that is real basic and only has some static info, but I don't want to put it in the Public Market with the Hidden option enabled because that doesn't seem secure enough.  It seems like if there was a way to verify that the user has a company email account setup on the phone on startup that would unlock the app, but I dont think thats possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no features in assisting for enterprise apps. You'll have to verify the authenticity of the user in your application, by requesting credentials, or requiring the application to be on a company network (or visa versa).

As for distribution, hidden publication is the only real option you have, as beta-distribution is limited to a few accounts.